# Implicit conversion to const string reference fails

Tags: c++

Why does changing the function parameter of `Foo` and `Bar` from `const` to `non-const` result in different compiler errors?
Or in other words: why is `Foo(false)` ok, while `Bar(false)` result in a compiler error?

```
#include <string>

void Foo(const std::string &test)
{
}

void Bar(std::string &test)
{
}

int main(int , char* [])
{
    Foo(false);
    Bar(false); // error C2664: 'Bar' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'std::string &'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `const` is one thing, but I am surprised you are not asking about why `Foo(false);` works and `Foo(true);` doesn't, it seems much weirder no ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. This first part was answered in another question, therefore I am not asking again.

Comment: @nabulke: In this case, since they are irrelevant to this question, I would suggest you edit the calls out. Let's focus on what really matters to you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call your functions with a `bool` argument, the compiler will look for a viable conversion from `bool` to whatever type the argument has: `const std::string &` in the first case, and `std::string &` in the second case.

`std::string` is constructible from `const char *`, which **`false`, being an integral constant 0, is implicitly convertible to** (it will result in `nullptr`). Hence **a temporary string will be constructed** and bound to the const reference.

The same thing cannot be done with the non-const version of the reference, since the temporary object is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo(false)` is okay, since `string` has imlicit constructor, that receives `const char*`, so `false` will be converted to `0`, that will be sent to c-tor.

`Bar(false)` is incorrect, since you cannot bind a temporary to an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because `false` can be converted into `0`, and it's can be converted into `const char *` (especially `NULL`).

So, your code is equal to:

```
Foo(string((const char *)NULL));
```